# Mini-DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter Sound Stopped Working

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, external-display, mini-displayport

I have cancelled cable and want to watch the NCAA tournament games on my TV tonight through my 2011 Macbook Pro where I can stream the game in a browser.

I have a cheap Mini-DisplayPort to HDMI converter that I have connected to my TV in the past and had no issues with audio or video, the problem is the audio has stopped working since the last time I used it a few months ago and now just keeps playing through the laptop speakers, but the video works fine.

Everything with my setup is the same and **when I try to force the audio output to the TV in the Audio system settings, my TV is not listed as an output option at all.**

I have tried various combinations of power cycling, replugging-in both devices and making sure the TV options are set properly to receive audio through HDMI but no luck.

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cheap adapter was cheap and apparently the audio connection on these regularly gives out in just a few months.